# How to create a sub-certificate out of an existing certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I created a certificate in my server for the hostname `xxx.lol.example`. I want to know if it is possible to create a sub-certificate for the hostname `xxx.lmfao.lol.example` thanks to the initial certificate?

Comment: Hi, AmsoLit. Maybe you could provide more information how did you created certificate? What tools did you use, maybe OS and other information that could be helpful.

Comment: I want a chain like this : authority (me) <-- intermediate (me) <-- SSL certificate on my server <-- certificates that come from my first certificate for web sites host in my server.

I don't know if it is clear. It looks like this subject : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013515/how-to-create-a-sub-personal-digital-certificate)  but the difference is that I am my own authority of certification. 

I use xubuntu. I don't have more information :(

Answer (score 1):

You can not create "sub-certificate" out of a given certificate.

You need either to request a new separate certificate from some CA for your second name or you should create a new certificate that covers both names, which means putting the second name in the `subjectAlternateName` part of the certificate (your CA should help you with that).

If you are your own CA as you claim in comment (not clear from your question), then you can just produce whatever other certificate you need.